# JOLT: Copy key value and filter array

Tags: json, jolt

I'm trying to filter away some of the objects in the array that does not meet the condition in a given data. All the **idType** containing **"SAL_EMP"** and **"MAJ_EMP"** shall be removed and return only the remaining objects. But is currently not returning the "filtered" objects into its own parent.

How can modify my spec in order to achieve the desired result?

*Input data*:

```json
[
  {
    "type": "front-desk",
    "employeeIdDetails": [
      {
        "id": "900",
        "idType": "HR_EMP"
      },
      {
        "id": "100",
        "idType": "SAL_EMP"
      },
      {
        "id": "100",
        "idType": "MAJ_EMP"
      },
      {
        "id": "120",
        "idType": "COL_EMP"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "backend",
    "employeeIdDetails": [
      {
        "id": "920",
        "idType": "HR_EMP"
      },
      {
        "id": "600",
        "idType": "SAL_EMP"
      },
      {
        "id": "160",
        "idType": "COL_EMP"
      },
      {
        "id": "400",
        "idType": "MAJ_EMP"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "middle-end",
    "employeeIdDetails": [
      {
        "id": "220",
        "idType": "SAL_EMP"
      },
      {
        "id": "630",
        "idType": "SAL_EMP"
      },
      {
        "id": "460",
        "idType": "SAL_EMP"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

*Desired data*:

```json
[
  {
    "type": "front-desk",
    "employeeIdDetails": [
      {
        "id": "900",
        "idType": "HR_EMP"
      },
      {
        "id": "120",
        "idType": "COL_EMP"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "backend",
    "employeeIdDetails": [
      {
        "id": "920",
        "idType": "HR_EMP"
      },
      {
        "id": "160",
        "idType": "COL_EMP"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "middle-end",
    "employeeIdDetails": [
    ]
  }
]
```

My current Jolt spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "type": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,employeeIdDetails)": {
              "*": {
                "idType": {
                  "HR_EMP": {
                    "@2": "[]"
                  },
                  "COL_EMP": {
                    "@2": "[]"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "[&1].id",
        "idType": "[&1].idType"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Returning result as:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "900",
    "idType": "HR_EMP"
  },
  {
    "id": "120",
    "idType": "COL_EMP"
  },
  {
    "id": "920",
    "idType": "HR_EMP"
  },
  {
    "id": "160",
    "idType": "COL_EMP"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be walking through **employeeIdDetails** array in order to apply conditional logic while combining them with the other elements which have the key **type** as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "type": "@(1,type).&",
        "employeeIdDetails": {
          "*": {
            "idType": {
              "SAL_EMP": {
                "@2": "[]"
              },
              "MAJ_EMP": {
                "@2": "[]"
              },
              "*": {
                "@2": "@(5,type).&4"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

beneath the common keys named the values of the **type** elements, and then get rid of those auxiliary keys within the next level of transformation.

Comment: Thanks. It works but a bit of hard-coding in the specs. I was looking for a more flexible specs that can allow me to add additional key-values to the data.

Comment: you're welcome @AlexDonovan , your case is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Manage to figure out a specs from some samples online.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // item array
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "employeeIdDetails": {
          "*": { // fixes array
            "idType": {
              "HR_EMP|COL_EMP": { // only match the thing you want
                "@2": "[&5].employeeIdDetails[]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```